CharlesProxy can not inspect traffic from iOS to local server on mac?
I have watched this helpful video, how to inspect traffic from my phone to some remote server: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kcCeXwZj7c. It seems pretty straight forward and it works. I reach remote server with my iPhone and charles proxy records all the traffic.
Now I have also mac application that I can connect to from my iPhone, on that same mac. I also want to inspect that traffic (between my phone and app). However I get nothing in the Charles. I see in the phone logs that all requests get executed to local server, but Charles shows nothing.
Is it possible to do this?
EDIT:
After a lot of testing it seems the problem is that my requests from iPhone use computer name:
http://Username-MacBook-Pro.local:8000

If I change it to be:
http://192.168.1.103:8000

Then requests are recorded and everything is ok. I tried map remote / DNS spofing / rewrite / adding mapping to etc/hosts, but nothing, Charles it seems, can not resolve this / does not see these requests. So I am stuck, is there a way to make this work?
Newest Edit:
It seems that all this is a problem resulting from /Username-MacBook-Pro.local domain. It seems iPhone for some reason, i mean iOS, does not go through proxy if domain is .local. So it completely bypasses Charles. I don't know if this feature can be turned of somehow.

Have you tried if other apps that allow entering an URL act the same way? Nowadays there are a lot of different app development frameworks used, some use their own HTTP client and thus also their own proxy logic. Therefore the problem can be located in iOS but tit can also be located in the app itself.

Tried with safari same result
